# Getting 3d model normal information from OpenGL render output

Tags: opengl

i have a 3d model ,it has coordinate information, normal information, color information, etc. of each vertex, but I want to get the normal information corresponding to the rendered image is the same as the rgb image, what should I do, can you provide the reference code, I am a novice,  I don't know much about the application of opengl, thank you, thank you very much

Comment: The normal information is not stored anywhere. You need to write the normal vectors to a framebuffer. This question is way too broad. Actually you are looking for a tutorial. Read [LearnOpenGL - Deferred Shading](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Deferred-Shading)

Comment: thanks for your answer,your answer is vary useful for me!!!!